# Get exact results in a QUERY using CAST, BETWEEN and INTERVAL

Tags: sql

Below is the query for One week past due

```
Select count(*) as OneWeekPastDueNC from tblNAME WHERE 
ColumnNm = '9940081135'
AND
CAST(DueDt AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE "2020-03-19", INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE '2020-03-19'
```

Getting data results WITH DueDt 2020-03-20. Expecting that my date boundaries is from 2020-03-12 to 2020-03-19 only.

Comment: Your query seems okay. Can you please share some sample data?

Comment: The date condition looks fine to me. Are you sure you are getting 2020-03-20? (Just replace `count(*)` by `DueDt` and add `ORDER BY DueDt DESC` to the query to check this.) And please tag your request with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: the data in the date column has this 2020-03-13T00:00:00.000000000Z

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a database tag and it *should* work.  However, I would recommend not using the `date()` function and instead doing direct comparisons:

```
WHERE ColumnNm = '9940081135' AND
    (DueDt >= DATE_SUB(DATE '2020-03-19', INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
     DueDt < DATE '2020-03-20'
    )
```